# OpenSSL configure maximum number of connections

Tags: c++, c, openssl

My application holds between 950-970 SSL connections before it segfaults inside `SSL_read`.  Is it possible to configure OpenSSL to accept more connections than this?

I've programmed it to not do anything over the connections after acquiring them, so I know this is a function of # of open connections, not # of connections currently reading/writing or time.

Updates:

- Same error on ubuntu at the same place.  I'm working on ubuntu going forward.
- Same error if I double my machine size (RAM, swap, CPU) at the same number of connections.
- Context is not null.
- `ulimit -n` is set to 4096.  I've verified this by also setting `ulimit -100`, a different error is observed in that case.
- Issue happens even if threads are pooled.   Issue happens at the same number of connections, whether there is 1 thread / connection or 1 thread / 10 connections.

I am trying to build OpenSSL from source with debugging options enabled.  I'm starting to wonder if this will take hours or tell me anything useful though.  I have a question on that [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129826/build-openssl-on-linux-with-g-for-debugging)

I've determined the segfault is happening on this line in openssl v 1.0.1.c:

```
ssl_lib.c:968

968     return(s->method->ssl_read(s,buf,num));
```

Furthermore, I've determined that this is not segfaulting inside the `ssl_read` function (which ought to point to `ssl3_read`).   The member `ssl_read` of `method` is actually invalid itself and it appears `method` itself is also invalid (I'm inferring this on the basis of "strange looking address.")

Comment: Can you locate exactly where it is segfaulting?

Comment: Somewhere in SSL_read 3/4 times and once in SSL_get_error.  I don't know how to look inside closer than this with gdb, although I imagine it involves compiling from source, dummying out optimization, etc.

Comment: Is your system running out of memory, or some other resource, by any chance?

Comment: That's not impossible and I guess a C library would just segfault instead of give me an "out of memory" exception.  Is it possible to verify this?  I've also had to increase ulimit on # of files that can be opened.

Comment: What operating system is it running on?

Comment: 1,000 SSL connections will be quite resource intensive, it's not surprising that you're hitting some resource limit.  You'll have to use commands like `top` and `ps` to figure out what resource it's capping out on.  I assume it's memory, since that is very likely to give you hard errors, but OpenSSL should not, theoretically, be segfaulting, it should be giving an `out of memory` error.

Comment: Here are two guesses: 1) 950+ sounds close to 1024, which is a common limit on open fds, you might look into that; 2) are you checking that the context you're passing into SSL_read is non-null?

Comment: What commands do you run between the `accept` that creates the new connection and your first `SSL_read` or `SSL_write`?

Comment: @notfed - I've updated my post to include the line it's segfaulting on.

Comment: Is it multi-threaded? Are you creating one thread per connection? 1,000 SSL Connections *is* resource intensive. But, I guess with sufficient number of descriptors etc, it should work. Can you post the code related to SSL Connections here?

Comment: Well, it's a few hundred lines of code so that's not hugely practical.  Yes, one thread per cnxn.  It occurred to me yesterday that I may actually be hitting a thread limit, so I'm going to prototype a thread pool and see if that has an effect.

Comment: @Jay - even if the threads are pooled so relatively few threads per connection, error is observed the same. 
Could this relate to the fact that it fails at about 993 connections and gmail's SSL port is 993?

Comment: @djechlin, I don't think the SSL port has anything to do with limiting the connection.  Even if it did, it won't be crashing your code. Have you checked the stack size for each thread. Do a ulimit -a and find out the default stack size. Reduce the stack size per thread by ulimit -s and then try again.

Comment: @djechlin, Also, when you implemented thread pooling, how many threads did you create as a part of the pool?

Comment: @Jay - Just to scaffold I simply made 150 threads and put up to 10 connections in each thread.

Comment: I guess the particular memory where the SSL_S contents reside is getting corrupted due to which the s->method value is not correct. Can you check if there is any possibility of memory overwrite happening in your code? Also, is the 993rd SSL_S alone which is getting corrupted or is it randomly different SSL_S?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? It seems that I have the same problem.

Comment: @query can't remember, haven't worked on that project in 7 years.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, it seems like you reached some limit. As you said, the number file descriptors is OK. So, you could try increase stack size with `ulimit`. Eg:

```
ulimit -s 32768
```

Furthermore, you could use a tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), to help you find out what really is going on at the point your app segfaults.

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `valgrind`, which's use would definitly help here.