# Build OpenSSL on Linux with -g for debugging

Tags: debugging, build, compilation, makefile, openssl

I have a segfault coming from OpenSSL (specifically `SSL_read`) that I'd like to debug.  I think the best step to take here is to build the library myself with debug symbols so I can step into the function and see the command it's happening on.  It's not clear to me how to a) build the library myself and b) hack the makefile to give me the debug symbols.  Does anyone have experience doing this with this specific library, or have general guidelines on this sort of build and modify approach?

Got this error:

```
./config -d
Operating system: x86_64-whatever-linux2
This system (debug-linux-x86_64) is not supported. See file INSTALL for details.
```

Not sure what to do here.  OS info:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.2.0-24-virtual (buildd@yellow) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.31ubuntu5) ) #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 10:17:19 UTC 2012
$ uname -srvio
Linux 3.2.0-24-virtual #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 10:17:19 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can follow the simple instructions mentioned [here](http://www.devside.net/guides/linux/openssl) for building OpenSSL. For making a debug build, add the `-d` flag when you run `./config`, i.e. `./config -d [other options]`. Building OpenSSL is mentioned in detail [here](http://www.cgicentral.net/400CS/Docs/openssl/INSTALL.openssl.html).

Comment: Trying again with latest version...  I dumbly followed the first guide you posted which was written when 0.9.8c was current, I assume.

Comment: OK.  Muddled my way through from there, got it.

Comment: ./config -d is exactly what the original post author said he tried and received errors.  Unfortunately, this particular question and answer doesn't have much value since the actual solution was never posted anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

On new versions of OpenSSL, it looks like flags passed to ./Configure get injected directly into the gcc line when compiling. I just did `./Configure -g linux-x86_64` and successfully got debugging symbols in my build.

Answer (score 2):

After running the regular configure step, do the following from the shell:

```
$ find . -name Makefile | xargs sed -i -e 's#-O3#-g#g'
```

It modifies the generated makefiles; instead of optimization option `-O3` it puts in the `-g` option (generate debug symbols).